# Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)"

Tags: c#, oledb

I got an error like this

'Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Could not find installable ISAM.".' while transferring database from msaccess to SQL

I have written this code

```
try
{
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
    DataTable userTables = null;
    using (connection)
    {
       string mappath = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Path"].Value.ToString();
       string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"" + mappath + "", "*.mdb", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
       // c:\test\test.mdb
       foreach (string tr in filePaths)
       {
          connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + tr + "";
          string[] restrictions = new string[4];
          restrictions[3] = "Table";
          connection.Open();
          userTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);
          List<string> tableNames = new List<string>();
          for (int i = 0; i < userTables.Rows.Count; i++)
             tableNames.Add(userTables.Rows[i][2].ToString());
          try
          {
             foreach (string tableName in tableNames)
             {
                cn1 = new SqlConnection(con);
                if (cn1.State != ConnectionState.Open) { cn1.Open(); }
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * into [" + tableName + "] from OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','" + tr + "',[" + tableName + "])");
                cmd.Connection = cn1;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();---Got error Here
             }
          }
          catch (Exception Ex) { connection.Close(); }
          connection.Close();
       }
    }
 }
 catch (Exception Ex) { }
```

Would you pls solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a simple test on my local environment and the following works like a charm (this is from a C# console application):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string accessConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Temp\\StackOverflowDemo\\MyAccessDb.mdb;User Id=admin;Password =; ";

    using (DbConnection accessConnection = new OleDbConnection(accessConnectionString))
    {
        accessConnection.Open();

        using (DbCommand accessCommand = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            string accessQuery =
                "SELECT * INTO [MySqlTable] IN '' [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=(local);Database=MySqlDb;Uid=username;Pwd=password;] FROM [MyAccessTable]";

            accessCommand.CommandText = accessQuery;
            accessCommand.Connection = accessConnection;

            accessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested this with a MS Access 2002 database as my source and a SQL Server 2014 database as my target.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your information but I am using server database not local database

Comment: Hi the target database in this example runs on the server (it's a MS SQL Server)

Comment: Simply update the connection string and change server attribute with the name or ip address of your server.

Comment: I have already written this query like this 

select GLFIN12.* into [GLFIN12] IN [oledb];Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=vipl-user!@#$%;Persist Security Info=True;User ID= vipl-user;Initial Catalog=QQQ;Server=serverpc\sqlexpress FROM [GLFIN12]
but it is getting error
'IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).'

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but I see you are using SQL Express. Is it configured to accept remote TCP connections? Can you connect to it from other machines using for example Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: It's a good idea. I have n't tried that one till now i will try that other mechines

Comment: Let me know how it goed, I am curious ;)

Comment: No I am not getting the output i have tried in another mechines also

Comment: Sorry, does that mean you can connect to the SQL Express server from different machines?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the wrong connectionstring to connect to the SQL server (I am assuming you are trying to copy information from MS Access to MS SQL Server).

A valid MS SQL Server connection string would look something like this: `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`

For more information about connectionstrings please have a look at: http://www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: I tried that also by changing the connection string but no use getting same error.

Comment: I found a similar problem described here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5f60c377-4be3-46e6-8d84-2fc9fdbd8330/use-c-to-import-access-tables-into-sql-server

Maybe this will help you?

Comment: I tried this one also i got error like while executing the query 
'IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).  '


My code is

'OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * into 
["+tableName+"] IN "+con+" FROM "+tableName,connection);

                               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                               connection.Close();'