# I got error like this IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Tags: c#, sql

I got the error like this 'IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)'.

while executing the query to transfer the database from msaccess to SQL.

I have written this code

```
 try
           {
               string str = "";
               cn1 = new SqlConnection(con);
               if (cn1.State != ConnectionState.Open) { cn1.Open(); }
               str = "CREATE DATABASE "+db+" ON PRIMARY " +
                     "(NAME = " + db + "_Data, " +
                     "FILENAME = N'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\" + db + "Data.mdf', " +
                     "SIZE = 100MB, MAXSIZE = 100MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
                     "LOG ON (NAME = " + db + "_Log, " +
                     "FILENAME = N'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\" + db + "Log.ldf', " +
                     "SIZE = 1MB, " +
                     "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
                     "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";
               cmd1 = new SqlCommand(str);
               cmd1.Connection = cn1;
               cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
               cn1.Close();
               con = "ODBC; Driver={SQL Server};Server='" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Servers"].Value.ToString() + "';Initial Catalog=" + db + ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID= '" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["UserNames"].Value.ToString() + "';Password='" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Passwords"].Value.ToString() + "'";
           }
           catch (Exception Ex) { }
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
DataTable userTables = null;
using(connection) {
    string mappath = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Path"].Value.ToString();
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@
    "" + mappath + "", "*.mdb", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    // c:\test\test.mdb
    foreach(string tr in filePaths) {
        connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + tr + "";
        string[] restrictions = new string[4];
        restrictions[3] = "Table";
        connection.Open();
        userTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);
        List tableNames = new List();
        for (int i = 0; i < userTables.Rows.Count; i++)
        tableNames.Add(userTables.Rows[i][2].ToString());
        try {
            foreach(string tableName in tableNames) {
                //cn1 = new SqlConnection(con);
                //if (cn1.State != ConnectionState.Open) { cn1.Open(); }
                //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * into [" + tableName + "] from OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','" + tr + "';'Admin';'',[" + tableName + "])");
                //cmd.Connection = cn1;
                //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * into [" + tableName + "] IN " + con + " FROM [" + tableName + "]", connection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
        } catch (Exception Ex) {
            connection.Close();
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
} catch (Exception Ex) {}
```

And the query is like this

```
    select * into [ACTYPE] IN ODBC;
       Driver={SQL Server};
       Server='PC01';
       Initial Catalog=TARR;Persist Security Info=True;
        User ID= 'sa';Password='123' FROM [ACTYPE]
```

Comment: You seem to be running the insert in your access db - or did I read that wrong somehow.  Also what is in "con" .. its not mentioned in this, is this the sql server connection? as you seem to be transferring from sql to access in this code

Comment: I want to insert total access db into sql and i updated the question with con  i.e connection string

Comment: Nope the insert is still running on the access db

Comment: I want to transfer total database into sql database for that i have written this query 
select * into [ACTYPE] IN ODBC;
       Driver={SQL Server};
       Server='PC01';
       Initial Catalog=TARR;Persist Security Info=True;
        User ID= 'sa';Password='123' FROM [ACTYPE]
would u pls find out why it is getting

Comment: the error you're getting from access is usually about an invalid use of a keyword - but of course you googled that right? the format of the "in" statement looks wrong.  Where did you find this syntax from?

Comment: I have taken this syntax from this link  

social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/

Previously i got the error 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847932/cannot-initialize-the-data-source-object-of-ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb/31848223?noredirect=1#comment51617766_31848223

In that someone has suggested me this answer

Comment: your SQL isnt remotely like theirs, and is invalid I suggest you reread the suggestions.